# Next.js project build error: Entry point for implicit type library 'build'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to build nextjs project and getting this error:

```
Type error: Cannot find type definition file for 'build'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'build'
```

how can I build without this error?

This is how package.json looks:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "license": "fa",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment": "^33.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^33.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block": "^33.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^4.0.0",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/": "ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "dompurify": "^2.3.6",
    "highlight.js": "^11.5.0",
    "isomorphic-dompurify": "^0.18.0",
    "mobx": "^6.4.2",
    "mobx-react-lite": "^3.3.0",
    "next": "^12.1.5",
    "nextjs-progressbar": "^0.0.14",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.27.1",
    "sass": "^1.49.9",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.25",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.6",
    "eslint": "8.10.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  }
}
```

I am trying to build using yarn build command

Why am I getting this error and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: what command are you running to build the project?

Comment: @davidvarela_us I am running `yarn build`

Comment: And what does your package.json include for that command? Most likely either not build, or missing dependencies.

Comment: You get the same error if you run `npx next build` directly?

Comment: @Lissy93 yeah, getting the same error

Comment: Have you got subdirectories of a `typeRoots` directory (such as  `node_modules/@types`) that do not actually contain an `index.d.ts`, anywhere in your project?

Comment: Is this line correct? `"@types/": "ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment",`

Comment: That line is the source of your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused by this line in your `package.json`:

```json
"@types/": "ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment",
```

Looks like `yarn add` gone wrong. Uninstall that, remove it from your package.json, and you should be good to go :)

This issue occurs when you have subdirectories of a `typeRoots` directory (in this case `node_modules/@types`) that do not contain `index.d.ts`.

I agree, not a very clear error message. For more info, [Microsoft/TypeScript #27956](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27956) discusses this same problem.